# How do I remotely access an SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, remote-access, remote-server

This question has been edited for clarity...

Say I have a MySQL database, what are my options for performing queries from a remote computer and having access to the resulting data.

A convoluted solution I can think of is to have a web service that receives a query from a request and responds with an xml file of the results, but this seems like a bad way of doing it. What other options do I have of accessing a database remotely?

Comment: The possible answers highly depend on the reason why you want to connect to the database. Do you want to browse the content, modify it or write an application that accesses the data?

Comment: An application would access the data for read-only purposes

Comment: Do you want to write that application or use something that already exists? If you want to write it: can you specify the language you want to use? If you prefer the second option, we need to know the operating system and whether you want a standalone application or a web application.

Comment: Id like to write it. I'm using Linux and MySQL. I'm thinking of using Java.

Comment: mysql -h(host) -u(username) -p(password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are going to write a Java application to connect to a MySQL database you have a few options:

- use JDBC directly as described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html
- Hibernate (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/) but that may be a little bit too complicated
- Spring Data, here is a nice tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/
- JDBI (http://jdbi.org/) extremely simple ;)

Comment: So a database driver will allow software to connect to a remote database? If I were to use a different language, would I use odbc? Thanks for the answers so far

Comment: Yes, you need a driver and something that communicates with the driver. In this case jdbc (other solutions use jdbc internally). The answer is language-specific, in other languages you use different tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows machine you can use MySQL Workbench and then you can just provide the details of the server where MySQL is hosted.

You can also use putty to do SSH if MySQL server is hosted in Linux.
Steps:

List item

1. SSH to the Server where MySQL server is hosted.
2. mysql -u root -pyourpassword.

Comment: If a ssh to it and perform my commands remotely, how can I process the data locally?

Comment: when you put   mysql -u root -pyourpassword  , it will log you into MySQL and then you can choose your database i.e use testdatabase ;

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

1)
mysql -u {username} -p{password} -h {remote server ip} {DB name}

2)

In Windows :

-- Login to another system using putty or rdesktop

-- Access mysql database after login

In Linux:

-- ssh to another system using "ssh user@ip"

-- Access mysql database after login

You can follow this link for more details:

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html